# decimal point problem in integer, Delete unnecessary decimal points when reading and writing Excel files

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I used function

```
#1)
df<-read_excel(excelfile.xlsx, col_types='text')
#2)
df<-read_excel(excelfile.xlsx) %>% mutate_it(is.numeric, as.character)

df %>% openxlsx::write.xlsx('result.xlsx')
```

In both cases, integers have unnecessary decimal points.
for example,
original excelfile.xlsx have 1, 2, 3
but result.xlsx have 1.0,2.0,3.0

I want that result have 1, 2, 3

how to solve this problem?

and

The reason I converted a number to a character is because I got an error when I used bind_rows with another df.

```
Can't combine `..1$A` <character> and `..2$A` <double>.
```

Comment: `read_excel()` will guess column types, though you can override that with the `col_types` argument.

Comment: I used  ```col_types='text'``` argument.. but still zero decimal exsists in result file.

Comment: With `df <- read_excel(excelfile.xlsx)` my result is a tibble of doubles (i.e. floating point values). To convert those to integers I'd use `as.integer()`.